# Detecting a parasitic voltage/current that differs from line frequency

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, frequency

I have a question related to electronics:

"Someone told you that there might be a problem with the electrical circuit: In addition to the standard 50Hz alternative voltage, it mights exist another disruptive frequency at 50.5Hz.

For how long, at least, should you measure the voltage in the outlet to know if this disruptive frequency actually exists or if it is a fake information ?"

The answer is **2 seconds**, but I can't understand why. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference frequency is 0.5 Hz - that's a clue.

Comment: In another forum, clear explanation didn't given. That's why I asked here.

Comment: But I got the explanation that I want here.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Note that pretty much all questions here are "Problems with Electrical Circuits" so your question title doesn't help explain what aspect of electrical engineering the question is about. Something like "Mains frequency measurement time" would be much more informative. On this site we thank afterwards by upvoting useful answers and accepting the best one if your question has been answered satisfactorily. There's a [Tour] which explains how the site works. You can [edit] your questions and answers anytime to improve them.

Comment: I fixed your title for you to give you an example of how you might improve your question.  You say you got the explanation that you want, but looking at your one answer that has a downvote, it's not clear if that was the information you hoped for or if Andy's question helped you solve it.  For the benefit of future readers who come with the same question, it would be good if you participated a little more.  The reason Andy gave you a socratic question is for school questions we have a minimum effort standard before we answer.  Typically if you meet the standard you'll get concrete help.

Answer (score -1):

If a large motor with inertia is running at 50 Hz and grid hypothetically shifted 0.5Hz the current would change within 2 seconds or 1/f and might last longer as it reaches steady state.

This is why the grid only changes slowly to ensure load does not exceed supply by lowering f. Then return to normal or higher slightly in anticipation of next expected wave of load power.

Comment: What did U not understand Andy?